# Why doesn't sizeof parse struct members?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I know that `sizeof` is a compile-time calculation, but this seems odd to me:  The compiler can take either a type name, or an expression (from which it deduces the type).  But how do you identify a type within a class?  It seems the only way is to pass an expression, which seems pretty clunky.

```
struct X { int x; };
int main() {
    // return sizeof(X::x); // doesn't work
    return sizeof(X()::x); // works, and requires X to be default-constructible
}
```

Comment: Support for `sizeof(X::x)` is included in C++0x (cf. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2253.html).

Comment: @James +1 at your comment. My answer(deleted) should have been a comment actually, because Tom didn't mention C++0x. Maybe he wants it in C++98 :)

Comment: Yes, my question is about C++98.  However, even if I build with `-std=c++0x`, it doesn't work (GCC 4.3.2).  Are there any compiler implementations that do support it yet?

Comment: Intel C++ Compiler 11.1 does not support it.  GCC 4.4 includes support for it (per http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html; I don't have an installation of GCC to test it).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An alternate method works without needing a default constructor:

```
return sizeof(((X *)0)->x);
```

You can wrap this in a macro so it reads better:

```
#define member_sizeof(T,F) sizeof(((T *)0)->F)
```

Comment: AFAIK, dereferencing a NULL pointer is undefined behavior. Does that rule apply in this case also?

Comment: @AraK:  I don't think so:  "The operand [of sizeof] is either an expression, *which is not evaluated*, or a parenthesized type-id" (5.3.3/1; emphasis mine).

Comment: The NULL pointer is never dereferenced. This is a compile-time operation. It's just merely to get the compiler to do The Right Thing(tm).

Comment: Isn't that 'return sizeof...' the same as the offsetof?

Comment: @tommieb75: The *sizeof* `x` is the number of bytes occupied by the `x` member. The *offsetof* `x` is the number of bytes `x` is offset from the start of its enclosing structure `X`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution without the nasty null pointer dereferencing ;)

```
struct X { int x; };

template<class T> T make(); // note it's only a declaration

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(make<X>().x) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just say `extern T fakeT; sizeof(fakeT.x);` ?

Answer (score 0):

What about `offsetof`? Have a look [here](http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/10/29/checking-sizeof-or-the-offset-of-a-member/). Also have a look [here](http://www.embedded.com/columns/technicalinsights/18312031?_requestid=93318), which combines both `sizeof` and `offsetof` into a macro.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't help, because the compiler (while required to order the elements of the structure in the declared order) is free to pad them as it deems necessary.